# How to get CommandButton collection?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to list the captions of a large number of old ActiveX command buttons on a worksheet.

How do I refer to the collection?

PseudoCode:

```
For each btn in Activesheet.CommandButtons 
     Debug.Print btn.Caption
Next btn
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim s As Worksheet

Set s = ActiveSheet

Dim o As OLEObject

For Each o In s.OLEObjects

    If TypeName(o.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
        Debug.Print o.Object.Caption
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated the code that i found from MrExcel website:

```
Dim BtnActX As Integer
Dim MyShapes As OLEObjects
Dim Btn As OLEObject

'OLE Programmatic Identifiers for Commandbuttons = Forms.CommandButton.1
Set MyShapes = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
For Each Btn In MyShapes
If Btn.progID = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then
BtnActX = BtnActX + 1
abc = Btn.Object.Caption
MsgBox "command button text is: " & abc
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

How about looping through the `OLEObjects` in your worksheet, you can use their `progID` and see it it equals "Forms.CommandButton.1".

**Note**: please don't use `ActiveSheet`, instead use fully qualified objects, like `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindCommandButtonsInOLEObjects()

Dim Sht                 As Worksheet
Dim Obj                 As OLEObject

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name

' loop thourgh all OLE objects in "Sheet1"
For Each Obj In Sht.OLEObjects
    If Obj.progID Like "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then ' <-- check if current object is type Comman Button
        Debug.Print Obj.Object.Caption
    End If
Next Obj 

End Sub
```